# What does 'DD' mean in a name on GEDmatch.com?

Tags: autosomal-dna, gedmatch.com, terminology

On GEDmatch.com I've seen numerous matches that include a `DD` prefix on a name like:

> DD Mary Brown

What is this convention and what does `DD` stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "DD"-prefix simply means that they're a member of the Facebook group "[DNA Detectives](https://www.facebook.com/groups/DNADetectives/)".

It's a Facebook group for people who use DNA genealogy to track down family members. If you're on Facebook, and join that group you can contact the person using the prefix who might then be able to help with your research.

---

There's a handy little [Genetic Genealogy Glossary](http://thednageek.com/a-genetic-genealogy-glossary/) that can be really helpful with some of the jargon that's evolving in the world of DNA genealogy.